# SQL querying using excel vba via an ODBC connection

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I have created an excel macro to run SQL queries for my finance department as they are not SQL experts and it helps save time and effort.

Now, the issue is we have 2 locations (Manchester/Romania). I am based out of Manchester & the excel macro runs perfectly without any issues. However, users in Romania are unable to run any query using the same excel macro.

The users in Romania get the "Select Data Source" pop-up [Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE4Uf.jpg)asking them to select the source whereas there is no pop-up when we run the macro from Manchester.

The database on which the query is run is the accounting database. And, there are no issues running or connecting to the accounting software .i.e. front end.

So, the only issue is when running the excel macro to connect to the database and run additional SQL queries for operations and reporting needs of the department.

Is there anything which I have missed?
I would really appreciate any help or assistance in this regard.

Thanks & Regards,
SS

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=PT1-DB;UID=SRX_ANALYST_1;PWD=xxxxxxxxx;DBQ=PT1.WORLD;DBA=R;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSucces" _
        ), Array( _
        "sful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F")), _
        Destination:=Range("A1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = QRY_VAR
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "REPORT_SELECTION"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Is the `PT1-DB` ODBC DSN defined in Roumania?

Comment: Hello Robert, I believe it to be defined. The reason being the "Select Data Source" pop-up shows up in the pop-up (Image added to my original question).

Comment: Yes, the DSN names are the same. The definition could be different though. You might try to recreate the DSN with the exact same parameters. If that does not work, then there is most likely differences elsewhere like username, password, etc. Difficult to tell.